# Assumptions function not fully integrated in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I was doing homework with the python SymPy package where I met a problem.

Suppose integrate a function

```
    psi1=A*exp(k1*x)
```

from negative infinity to a fixed point a; the integrate function won't gave the exact result unless declare k1 to be positive.
The simply solution was to put positive=True in the argument before use it, i.e.

```
    Symbol(k0,positive=True).
```

However, I ran into another set of function called [assumptions module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html#module-sympy.assumptions)

[Assumptions module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html#module-sympy.assumptions)  and [Assuming functions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/assume.html)  whcih was quiet power syntax. But the problem was that, if I declare k1 to be positive in the above methods i.e.

```
 global_assumptions.add(Q.positive(k1))
```

or

```
 with assuming(Q.positive(k1)):
```

the integration

```
 integrate(psi1,(x,-oo,a))
```

would not calculate the exact result. I tried to use .evalf() and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["new" assumptions module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html#module-sympy.assumptions) is not (yet) integrated with the rest of SymPy, so making assumptions with it has no effect on your computations.

Placing assumptions on symbols at the time of their creation, like `Symbol(k0, positive=True)`, is currently the only way to have that assumption be used by SymPy.